Knot signature skein relation
Using this answer, I've managed to wrap my head around the proof of the knot signature skein relation, modulo one minor detail. How do we know that $s(K_+)-s(K_-) \geq 0$? How can we exclude the possibility that $s(K_+)-s(K_-) = -2$?
I think the answer I am looking for will come down to some very basic algebraic considerations. Any help filling this gap would be greatly appreciated!
